# git commit hash of an external loadable module

Tags: git, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm developing a Linux kernel module outside of the Linux source tree (in the standard way) and am trying to automatically include the git commit hash of the **driver** into the version string printed out during the module load. The Makefile computes the git hash using the command

```
DRV_TAG   := $(shell git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h")
```

but this picks up the git hash of the Linux tree and not my driver. Can you tell git to look at a particular directory when executing commands, or alternatively, is there is a better way of approaching this problem?

This is using git 1.5.4.5 and Linux 2.6.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `--git-dir` option which you should set to the appropriate `.git` directory. Also, while you can use `git log`, for what you're doing `rev-parse` (a plumbing command) might be more suitable.

```
git --git-dir=/driver/root/.git rev-parse HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

`git` takes an option `--git-dir` which lets you specify what repository to look in. There's an analogous `--work-tree` option if you need to look at the work tree too.

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo log -1 --pretty=format:"%h"
```

Look at the [git man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) for descriptions of these and other options.